# Can not deserialize JSON POST req to WCF using DataContract Name attribute

Tags: c#, json, post, serialization, datacontract

I have a WCF service receiving a POST request from a client in JSON format. In my service I have a DataContract'ed class, that should deserialize my request. Class filed names are not the same as in JSON object. So I use Name attribute to define binding between JSON object fields and WCR class fields. But it does not deserialize that way. Only if I use the same filed names in both JSON object and WCF class, I get request data correctly.

```cs
    [DataContract]
    public class ModifyBatchRequest
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "type")]
        public int TypeID { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "off", IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public int Offers { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "created", IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public RuleData[] NewEntries { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "updated", IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public RuleData[] UpdatedEntries { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "deleted", IsRequired = false, EmitDefaultValue = false)]
        public int[] DeletedEntries { get; set; }
    }
```

*this obj deserialized correctly if being send*

```
{
 TypeID: newOfferTypeId,
 Offers: requestOffers,
 NewEntries: self.newEntries.map(iPrepareEntry),
 UpdatedEntries: self.updatedEntries.map(iPrepareEntry),
 DeletedEntries: self.deletedEntries
};
```

*this does not*

```
{
type: newOfferTypeId,
off: requestOffers,
created: self.newEntries.map(iPrepareEntry),
updated: self.updatedEntries.map(iPrepareEntry),
deleted: self.deletedEntries
};
```

Comment: Could you please share test project(Github) with this example?

Comment: @BasilKosovan, I am not a ASP pro, so hardly can I make a test project, reproducing this problem =(

Comment: By default wcf use SOAP/XMl not JSON. Maybe it's the reason why it doesn't work. Try send xml body.